# Laravel 5.1: Scheduled Job Output mixed with all job

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5.1, job-scheduling

Using Laravel 5 schedule job I noticed that when there is more than one job working at the same time, the output of the jobs, is mixed!

Something weird, because if they run for several minutes and each has simple output like:

```
Job X, step 1: complete
Job X, step 2: complete
Job X, step 3: complete
```

The output that I get in an "Scheduled Job Output" email will be:

```
Job 1, step 1: complete
Job 2, step 1: complete
Job 2, step 2: complete
Job 1, step 2: complete
Job 1, step 3: complete
```

In additional sometimes I get more than an email for a job, like 2 or more emails incompleted. Only the last one is full of the output.
like:

1° email:

```
Job 1, step 1: complete
```

2° email:

```
Job 1, step 1: complete
Job 1, step 2: complete
```

3° email:

```
Job 1, step 1: complete
Job 1, step 2: complete
Job 1, step 3: complete
```

I know for sure that are the same jobs, because at the top of the output I print timestamp and name of the job.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because to send the output email, laravel saves the job with ->sendOutputTo($FILE_PATH)

If you use the same $FILE_PATH for multiple jobs that works concurrently, the output will be messy as described.